# How to add a TextBlock to a Canvas using UserControl class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

here is the XAML...

```
<Canvas Name="myCanvas">
  <TextBlock Name="myBlock" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="100" Foreground="Red" Text="R" Height="105" Width="96" Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="80" /
</Canvas>
```

I have a partial class that extends a userControl.

```
public partial class Card : UserControl
```

I also have a test form that uses this control like this,

```
public formTest()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Card1.drawText();
  myCanvas.Children.Add(Card1); //myCanvas is defined in XAML
}

Card Card1 = new Card();
```

How do add an instance of TextBlock to myCanvas when TextBlock is inside my UserControl? So lets say,

```
public partial class Card : UserControl
{
  private TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
  public Card()
  {
    txtBlock.Text = "Test";
    txtBlock.Foreground = brushFill;
  }
  public void drawText()
  {
    //uhhh idk
  }
}
```

In general I don't understand how to get anything to display without defining it in the XAML then adding properties via code. Like this I create an instance of TextBlock, give it some properties... then I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated. I also know I should be using a User Control but I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserControl should also have a XAML file associated, and the TextBlock should be inside that XAML.

The other option would be `Card : Control` (not  UserControl) and then you would need a template.

In neither coase can/should you try to add a TextBlock from inside a Control to myCanvas.

Seems you ought to read up on WPF UserControls and Custom Controls.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a simple TextBlock and add it to the canvas, you'll want to do something like this:

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "Text";
myCanvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

Then you can manipulate everything you have added to the Canvas via methods in Canvas.Children.